# changing Url redirection after submit according to which radio input is selected

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, action

Hy, i know a lot of topic are already open about this topic but i have read a lot of them since 3 hours and i don't understand how it's work.

I try to make a form who when one radio button is selected the URL change after the submit.

```
<form id="signin" action="">
<input type="radio" name="pro" value="pro"><span>pro</span><br>
<input type="radio" name="perso" value="perso"><span>perso</span><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

when "pro" is selected the URL is u1.html
when "perso" is selected the URL is u2.html

i saw a lot of topic using .attr() but i'm really a beginner in jquery i have trouble to understand the meaning (even with the documentation and the Q&A).

think a lot and sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Did you mean change action url ?

Comment: You need to use same value for name for both radio inputs if you are making if-else decision. On your question for .attr , it's a method that allows you to extract the property of an html control, like id value etc if they are defined.

Answer (score 0):

- Your `radio button`'s should have the same `name` attribute.
- To change action URL that data will send to, use `$("#signin").attr("action", url);`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //add change listener to all inputs with name account
  $("[name='account']").change(function() {
    //get current radio button value
    var ch = $(this).val();
    var act = "";
    //determine pro || perso
    if (ch == "pro") act = "u1.html";//set url
    if (ch == "perso") act = "u2.html";//set url

    $("#signin").attr("action", act);//set action url
    console.clear();
    console.log("Data will send to: " + act);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="signin" action="">
  <input type="radio" name="account" value="pro"><span>pro</span>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="account" value="perso"><span>perso</span>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Work perfectly ! thinks a lot !